# Subsequence such that $c(a(n))=2^n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, oeis

Let $a(n)$ be [A060831](http://oeis.org/A060831), i.e., $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\operatorname{number of odd divisors of} k$.

Let
$$\ell(n)=\left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor$$
Let
$$b(n,k)=2b(n,k-1)-2^{k-1}, b(n,0)=n$$
Let $c(n)$ be the sequence of even numbers $k$ such that $b(k,\ell(k)+1)\equiv 0 \pmod k$.

Let $d(n)$ be [A082662](http://oeis.org/A082662), i.e, numbers $k$ such that the odd part of $k$ is less than $\sqrt{2k}$.

I conjecture that $c(n)$ is a subsequence of $d(n)$.

I also conjecture that $c(a(n))=2^n$.

One may verify last conjecture using the following PARI prog:

```
f(n)=my(A=n); for(i=0,logint(n, 2), A*=2; A-=2^i); Mod(A, n)
my(z=1, z1=0, A=0); for(k=1, 59, while(!(f(2^(z1+1)*(2^z1+z-1))==0 && z<=3*2^z1), if(z>=3*2^z1, z1=z1++; z=1, z++)); my(B=2^(z1+1)*(2^z1+z-1), C=logint(B, 2)==valuation(B, 2)); A+=C; print([k,C,A,B]); z++);
```

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: The sequence $c(m)$ is made of numbers of the form, $m=2^{nl-1-\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor}n$ where $n$ are all odd natural numbers and $l\in\mathbb N$. This satisfies the condition that $n<\sqrt{2m}$.

Comment: @AlapanDas, thank you for comment! Very nice observation! Do you have a proof?

Comment: From the recurrence relation of $b(n,k)$ we get, $b(n,k)=2^{k-1}(2n-k)$. Now, if $c(n)$ is comprised of even numbers s.t $m=2^a_1n$, where $n$ is odd, we have $l(m)=a_1+\lfloor \log_2{n} \rfloor$,then $b(m,l(m)+1)=2^{l(m)}(2^{a_1+1}n-l(m)-1)$

Now, $m \mid b(m,l(m)+1) \Rightarrow n \mid l(m)+1$, say, $l(m)=nl-1,l \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: @AlapanDas, thank you very much!

Comment: @AlapanDas, could you please tell me your e-mail? I would like to share with you an idea for an article.

Comment: Ok. My email is: adas2001.suri@gmail.com